# Serializing jagged vs multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, reflection, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have an `object` that is of type `Array` (that is `object.GetType().IsArray` returns true). My question is how can I find out whether it is a jagged or a multidimensional array? Is there a way to serialize the array so that the code "doesn't know" the difference (using reflection)?

Note that the array is of arbitrary length/dimension. I was thinking that I could perhaps parse the `Type.Name` to search for `[,` (as in one part of `[,,]`) or `[][]` to distinguish between these -- but that still means I'll have two code paths for each case and I feel like there should be a better way to accomplish this than parsing type names.

For a jagged array, it seems easy enough to take the array and then keep indexing it using `[]` to iterate over all the elements, however, this approach does not work for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: you are writing a custom serialization mechanism?  why not use one of the several options that are built into the .net framework?

Comment: It's mostly a learning exercise :)

Comment: Try to look into the customization options of DataContractSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jagged array is an array of arrays.  So all you have to do is look at the element type and check that it is an array as well:

```
    static bool IsJaggedArray(object obj) {
        var t = obj.GetType();
        return t.IsArray && t.GetElementType().IsArray;
    }

    static void Test() {
        var a1 = new int[42];
        Debug.Assert(!IsJaggedArray(a1));
        var a2 = new int[4, 2];
        Debug.Assert(!IsJaggedArray(a2));
        var a3 = new int[42][];
        Debug.Assert(IsJaggedArray(a3));
    }
```

Cast to Array and use the Rank property to find the number of dimensions for a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I figured out I can also use `Array.Rank` to determine if an array is multidimensional (for which `Rank > 1` is true). This works great, thank you!